# choose "from" value from different mailbox

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook

How i could get (and choose) the right "from" value when creating a new mail in Outlook using C# ?

Let me explain better : for example i have one account "alex" and two mail box "Mailbox - Alex" and "Mailbox - pluto" (^_^) ... i wanna create a c# program that if I'm in the "Mailbox - Alex" it set the from value to "Alex" and if i'm in the other mailbox it choose the other from value .

Comment: you don't need to repeat tags like "C# Outlook" in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao Alessandro, see here: [C# Winforms: Accessing Outlook with Multiple Mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558415/c-winforms-accessing-outlook-with-multiple-mailboxes)